# Why index type is defined two times?

Tags: typescript

This is the example from typescript [official document](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html):

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    breed: string;
}

// Error: indexing with a 'string' will sometimes get you a Dog!
interface NotOkay {
    [x: number]: Animal;
    [x: string]: Dog;
}
```

What confuses me is the index type definition:

```
interface NotOkay {
    [x: number]: Animal;
    [x: string]: Dog;
}
```

In my impression, an index type is like an array (an object in javascript). You can only access the member by using "[]" operator, e.g.:

a[10], or a["Tom"].

Why the above example defined twice of index and return?
first time:

```
[x: number]: Animal;
```

second time:

```
[x: string]: Dog;
```

When using [] operator, which one should be the type? e.g. a[10]??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using [] operator, which one should be the type? e.g. a[10]??

In JavaScript (and therefore in TypeScript) objects can have properties with numbers as their name, for example:

```js
{
    1: 'Apples',
    2: 'Oranges'
}
```

Which is the same as:

```js
{
    '1': 'Apples',
    '2': 'Oranges'
}
```

The name of a property is also called a *key*.

> In my impression, an index type is like an array (an object in javascript).

Just because an object has numeric keys, it is *not* automatically an array:

```js
var arr = ['Apples', 'Oranges'];
console.log(arr.constructor); // logs 'function Array() { ... }'
console.log(arr[1]); // logs 'Apples'

var obj = { 1: 'Apples', 2: 'Oranges' };
console.log(obj.constructor); // logs 'function Object() { ... }'
console.log(obj[1]); // logs 'Apples'
console.log(obj['1']); // logs 'Apples'
```

Having said that, the interface `NotOkay` describes objects that are allowed to have *both* numeric and non-numeric keys. How they are accessed is not described or restricted by interfaces in any way.

> What confuses me is the index type definition

Yup. That's exactly what the TypeScript handbook you referred means with *'indexing with a 'string' will sometimes get you a Dog'*. Due to the loose syntax for accessors I just described it would be very confusing to have an object whose numeric keys let you access one type while the non-numeric keys let you access another.

For the sake of clarity: If you were to modify the example just a bit, there would be no error in the interface anymore:

```
class Animal {
    name: string;
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    //breed: string; <-- Dog and Animal now have the same interface 
}

// No error because Dog and Animal have the same interface:
interface Okay {
    [a: number]: Animal;
    [x: string]: Dog;
}
```

([TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0Aclass%20Dog%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fbreed%3A%20string%3B%20%3C--%20Dog%20and%20Animal%20now%20have%20the%20same%20interface%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20No%20error%20because%20Dog%20and%20Animal%20have%20the%20same%20interface%3A%0Ainterface%20Okay%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Ba%3A%20number%5D%3A%20Animal%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bx%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Dog%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0A))

This example is fine, because TypeScript uses a **structural type system**:

> Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping.
>   Structural typing is a way of relating types based solely on their
>   members. This is in contrast with nominal typing. [more...](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Based on structure type system, Animal and Dog are allowed to assign to each other. Therefore your playground example has no error. But why define two sets of index and return value, in which the return value can be considered to be same type?

Comment: A return value is a value returned from a function — I don't see any return statements of functions in your question :-/  Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu Didn't I answer your question? If not, let me know and I'll be glad to help. If so, accepting it would be nice ;-)